# Sewage smell from bathroom faucet after replacing

Tags: bathroom, sink, smell, sewage

[image]I just replaced the toilet, sink, and faucet in my bathroom and I now smell sewage from the sink. Everything is basically the same, although I had to get a drainpipe extender - still have p-trap though. Ideas?

Added pic but let me know if the angle is what you need and thank you!

Follow-up: since the sink and faucet I installed in the other bathroom don’t have this issue, ordered those exact products and going to reinstall to see if this remedies issue. Did not have to do the drainpipe extender on the other one and it was more exactly centered. Thanks for the thoughts and will update after I do that.

Comment: without picture we can not help you

Comment: What Ruskes said. You're missing something here. A picture will make it far easier for us to help.

Comment: Can you post some side view photos of drain pipe connection at wall? It's hard to see what's going on with the nuts there.

Comment: Where the short white tailpiece extension meets the black pipe below it, it looks like there is a disc shaped washer(?). I'm pretty sure that should be immediately below the black plastic nut instead, so tightening that nut compresses it to make a seal between the white pipe and black trap pipe below it. You may have a similar issue where pipe connects to wall, which might let sewer gas leak out there.

Comment: entirely witin the sink, the overflow hole at the top of the sink that drains within down to the bottom where the drain pipe connects, that can fill up with muck over time giving that sewage smell, and gnat flies.  Solution is to use some bleach and other cleaner but mostly drag your outside garden hose to there and blast it clean with 60+ psi water pressure.  Or pull the sink to blast it out outside.  The faucet and trap replacement is likely coincidental, was for me.

Comment: if you can't run garden hose to the sink then you could rig something up from the under sink water supply hose, disconnecting that hose from the faucet.  I think you can get a fitting for that hose end to attach to garden hose, then use a 10' garden hose and sprayer, rather than pulling the sink.

Comment: Agree with @ron Plus, the strainer/stopper in the sink can get mucked up and smell bad.

Comment: The question says the sink was "just replaced", I don't get the comments about build-up.

Comment: What is the black flying saucer above where the white and black pipes meet?  That will not be the source of the smell but if it is an indication that you have not packed the various joints with appropriate washers (some slip, some flat, some integrated) THOSE could be your problem.    Do an experiment: Remove all the trap parts, and cover the trap adapter coming out of the wall with a plug if you have one or freezer bag tied tightly to the pipe.  If the small goes away, you know the trap is the problem.

Comment: It's definitely a bad day if you have to start acclaiming Delta. "extra grommet" that I've never seen before and looks like *the one rib that's left* from a flexible that's been cut. Take the p trap loose, take all the nuts off and show me all their grommets. But if it doesn't even leak I don't see how you'd be getting enough air to smell. What's the blue stuff sticking out of where the drain stop arm enters and why doesn't it have a nut on it?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's the sink and not the toilet's wax ring that you also just did? Anything else happening like installing a whole house fan? New HVAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a plumber look at this and he said my work was just fine and that I just added an unnecessary gasket but wasn’t an issue. So… still have smell and I’m thinking I maybe it was venting a little below the sink before and now that I have it so sealed up, it’s all coming out the top? Just can’t spend more mental cycles on this so thanks for the input!

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.  If you have no intention to pursue an answer, and since the rest of us can only guess and propose diagnostics, I recommend you delete the question.   Also, I suggest that if you are short on mental cycles, breathing sewer gas will only make that worse.  :) :)  You should fix it.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/161615)

Comment: I’m short on mental cycles because a plumber I paid told

Comment: Rather - Someone who's  a bad excuse for a plumber took your money and didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably (we can't see *how* without a picture, but we can tell *what* from the stench reported) you've screwed up the trap venting or turned the trap into an S-trap that siphons dry in your rework and adding an extender. **Or** you simply have a leak on the "drain" side of the trap permitting gas to pass.

That needs to be fixed, either by correcting the drain layout or adding a mechanical vent in an appropriate location (air admittance valve, often called  "Studor" which is a brand name for one maker.)

Comment: Trap looks good. Except where it doesn't.